# Multiline Text In List View

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I try to make a winform contains the ListView as Details (ListView1.View = "Details")
This ListView has 2 SubItems and i need to Wrap String and put it to SubItem .

I can not use any component or user control that created by other Like TableXP or ...

I Use this Code :

```
lstShares.Columns.Add("Share Name",100);
lstShares.Columns.Add("Path",300);
lstShares.View = View.Details;
ManagementObjectSearcher shares = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Share");
foreach (ManagementObject share in shares.Get())
{
    lstShares.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new String[] { share["Name"].ToString(), share["Path"].ToString() + "\n" + "AAAA" }));
}
```

If  I use "\n" or Environment.NewLine anything don't change like below picture
[image]

Anybody has idea ?
TNX.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you add a pic of what you're trying to achieve or post relevant code.

Answer (score 12):

Consider using the DataGridView control instead.  It supports wrapping:

```
dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;
dgv.MultiSelect = false;
dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dgv.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() {
  HeaderText = "Share Name",
  ReadOnly = true,
  AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
  FillWeight = 25
});
dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() {
  HeaderText = "Path",
  ReadOnly = true,
  AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
  FillWeight = 75
});
var shares = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Share");
foreach (ManagementObject share in shares.Get()) {
  dgv.Rows.Add(new String[] { share["Name"].ToString(),
                              share["Path"].ToString() + "\n" + "AAAA" });
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can implement something like this

```
ListView lv = new ListView();
lv.Columns.Add("Header", 100);
lv.Columns.Add("Details", 100);
lv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Sachin", "Some details" }));
lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Stats", "More details" }));
lv.View = View.Details;
Controls.Add(lv);
```

Answer (score -4):

You can wrap to the next line in a listitem's text using the '\n' character, e.g.:

```
listView1.Items.Add("apples\noranges\nbananas");

listView1.Items.Add("kiwis\ngrapefruits\nwatermelons");
```