# Better way to display information listview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm looking for a way to display the information in the list view more efficiently. In other word is it possible to display the text below after a certain length. Like that you don't need to expand the column, it's just easier to see the information.

**I want the text to be displayed like this:**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>
> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
>
> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
>
> aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
>
> nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>
> nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: This might help ... unless you are tied to the listview! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103749/multiline-text-in-list-view

Comment: ListView Items can't have different heights, so even when you owner-draw wrapped text it will not be optimal..

Answer (score 0):

Assume your certain length is `40`, so I split the string for every row. Finally this form resize the column width by the content.

```cs
string str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";
int fixedLength = 40;
int strLength = str.Length;

listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add("My Text");
for (int i = 0; i * fixedLength < strLength; ++i)
{
    int newStartIndex = i * fixedLength;
    if (newStartIndex + fixedLength < strLength)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(str.Substring(newStartIndex, fixedLength));
    }
    else
    {
        // last line
        listView1.Items.Add(str.Substring(newStartIndex));
    }
}
listView1.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```